# DRF : How to include serialized object that is returned from model method in serializer as a field?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

DRF newbie here.

I'm trying to build an API for a school project. My project tree includes several applications and one is Profiles and the other is Trips.

profiles.models includes Driver and DriverSession Model.
trips.models includes Trip Model.

Below you can see the DriverSession Model I've created in profiles.models. I've added a model method 'get_active_trip' to be able to return the active trip of the driver -if it exists- to client application when it retrieves the corresponding DriverSession. If it does not exist I want trip field still included in the response with a value of None.

```
class DriverSession(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle)
    start_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'DriverSession'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Driver Sessions'

    # Model method to get active trip of the driver
    def get_active_trip(self):

        try :
            trip = Trip.objects.get(driver_session=self, Q(status='DI') | Q(status='OT'))
        except Trip.DoesNotExist :
            return None
        else :
            return trip
```

Here is the Serializer I've created for DriverSession model in profiles.models :

```
from trips.serializers import TripSerializer

class DriverSessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer class for DriverSession Model.
    """

    driver = DriverSerializer(read_only=True)
    driver_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

    vehicle = VehicleSerializer(read_only=True)
    vehicle_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

    start_timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    end_timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False, allow_null=True, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    trip = TripSerializer(source='get_active_trip', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DriverSession
        fields = ('id',
                  'driver',
                  'driver_id',
                  'vehicle',
                  'vehicle_id',
                  'start_timestamp',
                  'end_timestamp',
                  'trip')
```

And this is partial view of my Trip Model in trips.models :

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    rider = models.ForeignKey('profiles.Rider')
    driver_session = models.ForeignKey('profiles.DriverSession', null=True, blank=True)
    ....
    ....
```

And finally, following is the partial view of the serializer class I've created for Trip Model in trips.serializers:

```
from profiles.serializers import DriverSessionSerializer

class TripSerializer(drf_serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer class for Trip model
    """
    ....
    ....


    driver_session = DriverSessionSerializer(read_only=True)
    driver_session_id = drf_serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True, required=False, allow_null=True)

    ....
    ....
```

When I try to run the command 'runserver' I'm getting an import error in trips.serializers in which any of the profiles.serializers cannot be imported.

What am I missing here? How can I include serialized object that is returned from a model method in the corresponding serializer of the model as a field?

Comment: you have a circular import here. solve this problem and it'll work (either move both serializers into one place, or create different serializers. By the way, you'll get into troubles as you are trying to serialize a Driver, which has a Trip, that has a driver with a trip with a driver ... .

Answer (score 1):

you want to add your custom field to your serilizer 
you have to do some code like this :

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  my_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField('is_named_bar')

  def is_named_bar(self, foo):
      return foo.name == "bar" 

  class Meta:
    model = Foo
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'my_field')
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield